How to get the difference of 2 dates between the column B of current Row with the column A of the past row GROUPING with a column C?
i have big difficult to make an SQL code, i think the logic is specific...
I have 3 column:

A opening date, the datas are ordered by this column
a closing date (of a trade)
First, I want to get the time between two trades, the logic is to take the OpeningDate of the row-1 and substract with the ClosingDate of the row current and repeat...
Secondly, it's important to consider the third column, who is the broker, to make the calcul considering every broker.

I created a short exemple :



ID
OPEN_TRADE
CLOSE_TRADE
BROKER




1
2024-12-11 04:45:07.000
2024-12-11 04:45:08.000
BINANCE


2
2024-12-11 04:45:09.000
2024-12-11 04:45:27.000
BINANCE


3
2024-12-11 04:50:07.000
2024-12-11 04:50:52.000
BINANCE


4
2024-12-11 04:50:07.000
2024-12-11 04:50:32.000
COINBASE


5
2024-12-11 04:55:06.000
2024-12-11 04:55:08.000
COINBASE


6
2024-12-11 04:55:07.000
2024-12-11 04:55:25.000
BITGET


7
2024-12-11 05:05:07.000
2024-12-11 05:05:14.000
BITGET


8
2024-12-11 05:05:32.000
2024-12-11 05:06:01.000
BINANCE



The result i wish is :



ID
TIME_LAPS
BROKER




1
1 (because 04:45:09 - 04:45:08 = 1 seconds)
BINANCE


2
220 (because 04:50:07 - 04:45:27 = 220 seconds
BINANCE


3
880 (because 05:05:32 of row8 - 04:50:52 of row3  = 880 second)
BINANCE


4
374 (because 04:55:06 - 04:50:32 = 374 second)
COINBASE


5
NULL
COINBASE


6
582 (because 05:05:07 - 04:55:25 = 582 second
BITGET


7
NULL
BITGET


8
NULL
BINANCE



My query is:
with dummy as 
(
SELECT 1 AS ID, DATE '2024-12-11 04:45:07.000' as OPEN_TRADE, DATE '2024-12-11 04:45:08.000' as CLOSE_TRADE, 'BINANCE' AS BROKER from dual union all
select 2, DATE '2024-12-11 04:45:09.000', DATE '2024-12-11 04:45:27.000', 'BINANCE' from dual union all
select 3, DATE '2024-12-11 04:50:07.000', DATE '2024-12-11 04:50:52.000', 'BINANCE' from dual union all
select 4, DATE '2024-12-11 04:50:07.000', DATE '2024-12-11 04:50:32.000', 'COINBASE' from dual union all
select 5, DATE '2024-12-11 04:55:06.000', DATE '2024-12-11 04:55:08.000', 'COINBASE' from dual union all
select 6, DATE '2024-12-11 04:55:07.000', DATE '2024-12-11 04:55:25.000', 'BITGET' from dual union all
select 7, DATE '2024-12-11 05:05:07.000', DATE '2024-12-11 05:05:14.000', 'BITGET' from dual union ALL
select 8, DATE '2024-12-11 05:05:32.000', DATE '2024-12-11 05:06:01.000', 'BINANCE' from dual 
)
SELECT extract(SECOND FROM OPEN_TRADE - CLOSE_TRADE), 'fm00.000' AS TIME_LAPS -- TIME_BETWEEN_2_TRADES
--MAX(SECOND FROM OPEN_TRADE - CLOSE_TRADE)
--  OVER (ORDER BY OPEN_TRADE ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) max 
FROM dummy
ORDER BY OPEN_TRADE;

The DATE '2024-12-11 04:55:06.000' dont work on Oracle to create my dummy exemple...
I success to understand how to make the difference between two dates, is extract(SECOND FROM OPEN_TRADE - CLOSE_TRADE)
I dont understand how to make the most important part of the code playing with the current / past row and consider the group this part is very difficult for me.
thanks

Hint : lag function


When you subtract two dates in Oracle you get an INTERVAL expressed in days with a fractional value.  You cannot Extract SECONDs from it because Extract works on DATEs.   2) Since the result of the subtraction is already what you want, you can convert the days to seconds by multiplying by the number of seconds in a day.  3) Since Closing is bigger than Opening, you want to subtract Opening from Closing, not what you wrote.


Are OPEN_TRADE and CLOSE_TRADE of type TIMESTAMP or of type DATE? With DATE (which is Oracle's misnomer for a datetime) just (lead(open_trade) over (...) - close_trade) * 24 * 60 * 60. With timestamps, convert them into datetmes first: (cast(lead(open_trade) over (...) as date) - cast(close_trade as date)) * 24 * 60 * 60.

As to "The DATE '2024-12-11 04:55:06.000' dont work": It is TIMESTAMP '2024-12-11 04:55:06.000' or CAST(TIMESTAMP '2024-12-11 04:55:06.000' AS DATE).

Day, Hour, minute and second is extracted based on difference between next open trade and current close trade using LEAD and is then converted to seconds.
Fiddle
SELECT 
    ID,
    OPEN_TRADE,
    CLOSE_TRADE,
    BROKER,
    LEAD(OPEN_TRADE) OVER (PARTITION BY BROKER ORDER BY OPEN_TRADE) AS NEXT_OPEN_TRADE,
    CASE 
        WHEN LEAD(OPEN_TRADE) OVER (PARTITION BY BROKER ORDER BY OPEN_TRADE) IS NOT NULL
        THEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM (LEAD(OPEN_TRADE) OVER (PARTITION BY BROKER ORDER BY OPEN_TRADE) - CLOSE_TRADE)) * 86400 +
             EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (LEAD(OPEN_TRADE) OVER (PARTITION BY BROKER ORDER BY OPEN_TRADE) - CLOSE_TRADE)) * 3600 +
             EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (LEAD(OPEN_TRADE) OVER (PARTITION BY BROKER ORDER BY OPEN_TRADE) - CLOSE_TRADE)) * 60 +
             EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (LEAD(OPEN_TRADE) OVER (PARTITION BY BROKER ORDER BY OPEN_TRADE) - CLOSE_TRADE))
        ELSE NULL
    END AS TIME_LAPSE
FROM trades
ORDER BY id;

Output


To use a DATE data-type, you can subtract one date from another to get the difference in days and then multiply by 86400 to get seconds. You can use the LEAD analytic function to get the value of the next row:
SELECT id,
       ROUND(
         (
           LEAD(open_trade) OVER (PARTITION BY broker ORDER BY open_trade)
           - close_trade
         ) * 86400
       ) AS TIME_LAPS,
       broker
FROM   dummy
ORDER BY OPEN_TRADE;

From Oracle 12, you can also use MATCH_RECOGNIZE:
SELECT id,
       ROUND((next_open - close_trade) * 86400) AS TIME_LAPS,
       broker
FROM   dummy
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY broker
         ORDER BY open_trade
         MEASURES
           first_row.id          AS id,
           first_row.open_trade  AS open_trade,
           first_row.close_trade AS close_trade,
           next_row.open_trade   AS next_open
         AFTER MATCH SKIP TO NEXT ROW
         PATTERN ( first_row next_row? )
         DEFINE first_row AS 1 = 1
       )
ORDER BY OPEN_TRADE;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE dummy (id, open_trade, close_trade, broker) as
  SELECT 1, DATE '2024-12-11' + INTERVAL '04:45:07.000' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2024-12-11' + INTERVAL '04:45:08.000' HOUR TO SECOND, 'BINANCE'  from dual union all
  select 2, DATE '2024-12-11' + INTERVAL '04:45:09.000' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2024-12-11' + INTERVAL '04:45:27.000' HOUR TO SECOND, 'BINANCE'  from dual union all
  select 3, DATE '2024-12-11' + INTERVAL '04:50:07.000' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2024-12-11' + INTERVAL '04:50:52.000' HOUR TO SECOND, 'BINANCE'  from dual union all
  select 4, DATE '2024-12-11' + INTERVAL '04:50:07.000' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2024-12-11' + INTERVAL '04:50:32.000' HOUR TO SECOND, 'COINBASE' from dual union all
  select 5, DATE '2024-12-11' + INTERVAL '04:55:06.000' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2024-12-11' + INTERVAL '04:55:08.000' HOUR TO SECOND, 'COINBASE' from dual union all
  select 6, DATE '2024-12-11' + INTERVAL '04:55:07.000' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2024-12-11' + INTERVAL '04:55:25.000' HOUR TO SECOND, 'BITGET'   from dual union all
  select 7, DATE '2024-12-11' + INTERVAL '05:05:07.000' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2024-12-11' + INTERVAL '05:05:14.000' HOUR TO SECOND, 'BITGET'   from dual union ALL
  select 8, DATE '2024-12-11' + INTERVAL '05:05:32.000' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2024-12-11' + INTERVAL '05:06:01.000' HOUR TO SECOND, 'BINANCE'  from dual;

Both output:



ID
TIME_LAPS
BROKER




1
1
BINANCE


2
280
BINANCE


3
880
BINANCE


4
274
COINBASE


5
null
COINBASE


6
582
BITGET


7
null
BITGET


8
null
BINANCE



fiddle

With timestamps, the formula to get seconds can be simplified:
round(((lead(OPEN_TRADE) over(partition by broker order by open_trade)+0) - (CLOSE_TRADE+0))*86400,2) 


--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
CREATE TABLE dummy  ( ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
                      OPEN_TRADE TIMESTAMP,
                      CLOSE_TRADE TIMESTAMP,
                      BROKER VARCHAR(100)
                    );

INSERT INTO dummy (ID, OPEN_TRADE, CLOSE_TRADE, BROKER)
VALUES
    (1, TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-12-11 04:45:07.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-12-11 04:45:08.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), 'BINANCE'),
    (2, TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-12-11 04:45:09.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-12-11 04:45:27.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), 'BINANCE'),
    (3, TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-12-11 04:50:07.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-12-11 04:50:52.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), 'BINANCE'),
    (4, TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-12-11 04:50:07.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-12-11 04:50:32.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), 'COINBASE'),
    (5, TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-12-11 04:55:06.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-12-11 04:55:08.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), 'COINBASE'),
    (6, TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-12-11 04:55:07.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-12-11 04:55:25.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), 'BITGET'),
    (7, TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-12-11 05:05:07.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-12-11 05:05:14.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), 'BITGET'),
    (8, TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-12-11 05:05:32.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-12-11 05:06:01.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), 'BINANCE');

If OPEN_TRADE and CLOSE_TRADE columns are of TIMESTAMP data type you can cast them to DATE - get the difference in days - and calc the seconds out of the result. If the columns are of DATE datatype just ommit casting...
Lead() Over() analytic function fetches the value from next row (partitioned and ordered by as stated in OVER() part) ...
--      S Q L :  
Select    ID, 
          Round( (Lead(CAST(OPEN_TRADE as DATE)) Over(Partition By BROKER Order By ID) 
                   - CAST(CLOSE_TRADE as DATE)
                 ) * 24 * 60 * 60, 0 ) "TIME_LAPSE",
          BROKER
From      dummy
Order By  ID

R e s u l t :



ID
TIME_LAPSE
BROKER




1
1
BINANCE


2
280
BINANCE


3
880
BINANCE


4
274
COINBASE


5
null
COINBASE


6
582
BITGET


7
null
BITGET


8
null
BINANCE



fiddle
